# mysql Full outer join two table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
socials and social_links

I want all rows from first table and related rows from second table.

My code:

```
SELECT socials.*, social_links.*
FROM socials
LEFT JOIN social_links ON socials.id=social_links.social_id  
WHERE social_links.site_id=1
```

This code return 2 rows, but I want 4 rows where site_id=1.

First table socials:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Facebook |
| 2 | Instagram |
| 3 | Linkedin |
| 4 | Messenger |

Second table social_links:

| id | social_id | site_id | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | https://www.facebook.com/lolo |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | https://instagram.com/test |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | https://www.facebook.com/koko |

I want all rows from socials join with social_links where site_id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `where` add your condition in the join

```
SELECT socials.*,social_links.*
from socials     left join  social_links  on socials.id=social_links.social_id and social_links.site_id=1
```

Comment: very thanks , i do not know condition can be put in on